# How to get custom Windows folder pictures with transparency?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, images, icons

How can I get custom images/icons to be displayed in my folder's icons? I'm talking about icons with a transparent background.
Like on these folders:
[image]

When I try to change the folder image manually, transparency always gets lost replaced by white color which looks really ugly:

[image]

Can this even be done? Or is there maybe a Photoshop script to generate an icon like this?

Comment: There is no easy answer for this. For all practical purposes, you must create a completely new icon. Here is an icon you can use: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2GzI8cZDN1PcVdTakRLLU9DWm8/view?usp=sharing It can also be used as a starting point for more of the same. It isn't perfect but it doesn't look too bad. All of the source is included in case you want to make it better. I used, PhotoShop, InkScape and IcoFX to make it.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is to right click to floder and propertis, and after on this tab click for image selecting or in the picture "Kép választás" and now you can search the icon for the floder.:
Is there way for can change to this small icon, but this to complicate.
Just crate a icon and replace it.
[image]

(If the picture is too small, you can view also in [here.](http://i59.tinypic.com/rco58o.png))

Comment: How does that solve my problem? This would just completely change the folder icon.  I want a fopder icon with a custom transparent image inside of it.

Comment: Why don't download a floder icon and make from a icon form him?
Otherwise you must be modifeid the dll file which must harder as this method.
The dll path on there the picture.